# Замена дубликата в ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist

Здравствуйте, вопрос заключается в следующем: У меня есть ArrayAdapter со списком и EditText для ввода данных. Когда я ввожу данные и нажимаю кнопку отправить, данные отправляются на сервер а затем выводятся в адаптере. при нажатии на кнопку я в адаптере сразу показываю введённые данные, но как только с сервера приходят новые данные (т.е. то самое сообщение что я вводил в EditText) в адаптере получается дубликат 2-х последних item'ов.
Вот что я пытался делать...
тут я добавляю данные, и ставлю ID сообщения = 0.

```
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        ResponseMsgArray rms = new ResponseMsgArray();

        rms.setMsg(form_input_msg);
        rms.setNewMsg(getEndMsgId);
        rms.setMsg_id_us(Integer.toString(LV_USID));
        rms.setMsg_id("0"); // тут
        sAdapter.addData(rms);
```

А тут, как только мне ответ пришёл, я ищу ID=0 и пытаюсь удалить..

```
@Override
public void response(ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> response) {

    String id_msg;
    int size = response.size();
    int count = response.size() - 1;

    if(count > 0) {
        getEndMsgId = response.get(count).getNewMsg();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        id_msg= response.get(i).getMsg_id();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, id_msg);
    }
        if(sAdapter == null) {
            sAdapter = new ChatMsgAdapter(this, response);
            listView.setAdapter(sAdapter);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Array:: setAdapter" + getEndMsgId);
        } else {

            data = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                String old_msg = data.get(i).getMsg_id();

                 if(old_msg.equals("0")) {
                    sAdapter.remove(data.get(i));
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Удалено" + data.size() + "->" + old_msg);
                }
            }

            sAdapter.setData(response);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Array:: setData" + getEndMsgId);
        }
}
```

При таком раскладе происходит какая то рассортировка добавленных данных. Например добавляю имена (Вася, Петя, Саша), далее - список обновился, данные удалились..результат (Петя, Вася, Саша), далее, поступает снова запрос на сервер, новых данных нет, срабатывает обычный notifyDataSetChanged, и список приобретает свой прежний вид (Вася, Петя, Саша). Подскажите как правильно реализовать то что я пытаюсь? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так надо было сделать

```
for(int _i = 0; _i < data.size(); _i++) {

        String msg     = data.get(_i).getMsg();
        String old_msg = data.get(_i).getMsg_id();

        if (old_msg.equals("0")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < newData.size(); i++) {
                remove(data.get(_i));
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Удалено" + i + "->" + msg);
            }
        }
    }
```